# Android Image animation using AnimationDrawable not working

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I am working on a project that involves animating an image using a sequence of images that is generated randomly. Here's code I have right now that is not working (or at least it does not appear to work):

```
/**
 * Method to display the current sequence
 * TODO make an animation for the screen to use
 */
public void displaySeq() {
    ad = new AnimationDrawable();
    int j = 0;
    for(Integer i : sequence) {
        switch(i)
        {
        case Constants.RED:
            System.out.printf("%d - RED\n", j);
            ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle), 500);
            break;
        case Constants.BLUE:
            System.out.printf("%d - BLUE\n", j);
            ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_circle), 500);
            break;
        case Constants.GREEN:
            System.out.printf("%d - GREEN\n", j);
            ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle), 500);
            break;
        case Constants.YELLOW:
            System.out.printf("%d - YELLOW\n", j);
            ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.yellow_circle), 500);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.printf("%d - bad color: %d\n", j, i);
            ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle), 500);
        }
        j++;
    }
    // add a black circle to the end of the animation
    ad.addFrame(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.black_circle), 500);
    System.out.println("Number of frames: " + ad.getNumberOfFrames());
    indicator.setBackground(ad);

    indicator.post(new Starter());

}

class Starter implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ad.start();

    }

}
```

When I run the application and this method gets called, I see the printout in LogCat, but the indicator does not get animated. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the problem. It was being caused by an error in my XML file. Basically, when I made the layout.xml file in Eclipse and added the ImageView (`indicator`), Eclipse set the `android:src` parameter to the image I had selected. Changing `android:src` to `android:drawable` resolved the problem.